# Improving the prediction score by use of confidence level of classifiers on instances

Tags: python, machine-learning, boolean, text-classification

I am using three classifiers (`RandomForestClassifier`, `KNearestNeighborClassifier`, and `SVM Classifier`)  which you can see below:

```
>> svm_clf_sl_GS
SVC(C=5, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovo', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=41, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

>> knn_clf_sl_GS
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=3, p=2,
           weights='distance')

>> for_clf_sl_GS
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='entropy',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

During training, `RandomForestClassifer` gives the best `f1_score` followed by `KNearestNeighborClassifier`, and then `SVMClassifier` on the predictions from the data. Here is my X_train (standard scaled values, if needed you can ask how I got this) & y_train:

```
>> X_train
array([[-0.11034393, -0.72380296,  0.15254572, ...,  0.4166148 ,
        -0.91095473, -0.91095295],
       [ 1.6817184 ,  0.40040944, -0.6770607 , ..., -0.2403781 ,
         0.02962478,  0.02962424],
       [ 1.01128052, -0.21062032, -0.2460462 , ..., -0.04817728,
        -0.15848331, -0.15847739],
       ..., 
       [-1.18666853,  0.87297522,  0.47136779, ..., -0.19599824,
         0.72417473,  0.72416714],
       [ 1.6835304 ,  0.40605067, -0.63383059, ..., -0.37094083,
         0.09505496,  0.09505389],
       [ 0.19950709, -1.04624152, -0.18351693, ...,  0.4362658 ,
        -0.77994791, -0.77994176]])

>> y_train_sl
874     0
1863    0
1493    0
288     1
260     0
495     0
1529    0
1704    1
75      1
1792    0
626     0
99      1
222     0
774     0
52      1
1688    1
1770    0
53      1
1814    0
488     0
230     0
481     0
132     1
831     0
1166    1
1593    0
771     0
1785    0
616     0
207     0
       ..
155     1
1506    0
719     0
547     0
613     0
652     0
1351    0
304     0
1689    1
1693    1
1128    0
1323    0
763     0
701     0
467     0
917     0
329     0
375     0
1721    0
928     0
1784    0
1200    0
832     0
986     0
1687    1
643     0
802     0
280     1
1864    0
1045    0
Name: Type of Formation_shaly limestone, Length: 1390, dtype: uint8
```

As you can see my y_train is in Boolean form (i.e. where the instances are `True` and where `False`.

I want to improve the accuracy of the predictions further by use of `predict_proba` in such a way that when I see that predictions from the classifier (let's say `RandomForestClassifier` first) has a low confidence level (<60%) about particular instances it predicted (which is what I am supposed to find first), it moves to the next classifier (let's say `KNearestNeighborClassifier`) and check the confidence level of those instances by the next classifier on those instances, if it has a high confidence level compared to the previous classifier (>60%) accept the solution from that classifier instead, similarly if this classifier has a lower confidence level on the same instances still(<60%), move to the next classifier and do the same thing for the third classifier.

Finally, if the third classifier has a lower confidence level (<60%) too, I need to accept the solution from the classifier which has the highest confidence level among all three classifiers.

Since, I am new to Machine Learning I might be confusing you with some of the statements for which I apologize so just correct me where I am wrong.

**EDIT:**
X_test and y_test are shown below. I need to predict on the X_test_prepared and evaluate the predictions and y_test_sl using `f1_score`. The predicted y must have passed through all three classifiers and has the best confidence levels for all the instances.

```
>> X_test_prepared
array([[ 0.69961751, -0.11156033, -0.43852312, ..., -0.40967982,
         0.32099948,  0.32099952],
       [ 0.90256086, -0.54532856, -0.46399801, ..., -0.05752097,
        -0.54261829, -0.54261947],
       [ 1.67447042,  0.24530384, -1.0113221 , ..., -0.54844942,
        -0.26066608, -0.26066032],
       ...,
       [ 0.28104683,  1.52670909,  0.62653301, ..., -1.15596295,
         2.05859487,  2.05859247],
       [ 1.50595496,  0.84507934, -0.44109634, ..., -0.71277072,
         0.14474518,  0.14474398],
       [-1.63423112, -0.12690448,  0.48577783, ..., -0.36025459,
         0.29137477,  0.29137047]])

>> y_test_sl
1321    0
1433    0
1859    0
1496    0
492     0
736     0
996     0
1001    0
634     0
1486    0
910     0
1579    0
373     0
1750    0
1563    0
1584    0
51      1
349     0
1162    1
594     0
1121    0
1637    0
1116    0
106     1
1533    0
993     0
960     0
277     0
142     1
1010    0
       ..
1104    1
1404    0
1646    0
1009    0
61      1
444     0
10      1
704     0
744     0
418     0
998     0
740     0
465     0
97      1
1550    1
1738    0
978     0
690     0
1071    0
1228    1
1539    0
145     1
1015    0
1371    0
1758    0
315     0
71      1
1090    0
1766    0
33      1
Name: Type of Formation_shaly limestone, Length: 515, dtype: uint8
```

Comment: So to be clear: You want the to move onto the next classifier only if there are instances that the current classifier had confidence level < 60% and you want to train the next classifier only with the instances for which the current classifier had confidence < 60%, right?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You may want to look into ensembling methods.

Comment: Given my recent edit what do you think are the possible implementations for this @George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal here turned out to create an ensemble of classifiers and take the most "confident" (highest probability class) predictions of all classifiers. The code is below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X_train, y_train = make_classification(n_features=4) # Put your training data here instead

# parameters for random forest
rfclf_params = {
    'bootstrap': True, 
    'class_weight':None, 
    'criterion':'entropy',
    'max_depth':None, 
    'max_features':'auto', 
    # ... fill in the rest you want here
}

# Fill in svm params here
svm_params = {
    'probability':True
}

# KNeighbors params go here
kneighbors_params = {

}

params = [rfclf_params, svm_params, kneighbors_params]
classifiers = [RandomForestClassifier, SVC, KNeighborsClassifier]

def ensemble(classifiers, params, X_train, y_train, X_test):
    best_preds = np.zeros((len(X_test), 2))
    classes = np.unique(y_train)

    for i in range(len(classifiers)):
        # Construct the classifier by unpacking params 
        # store classifier instance
        clf = classifiers[i](**params[i])
        # Fit the classifier as usual and call predict_proba
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_preds = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
        # Take maximum probability for each class on each classifier 
        # This is done for every instance in X_test
        # see the docs of np.maximum here: 
        # https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html
        best_preds = np.maximum(best_preds, y_preds)

    # map the maximum probability for each instance back to its corresponding class
    preds = np.array([classes[np.argmax(pred)] for pred in best_preds])
    return preds

# Test your predictions  
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score
y_preds = ensemble(classifiers, params, X_train, y_train, X_train)
print(accuracy_score(y_train, y_preds), f1_score(y_train, y_preds))
```

If you want the algorithm to return the highest probabilities instead of the predicted class, have `ensemble` return `[np.amax(pred_probs) for pred_probs in best_preds]` rather than preds.

Comment: Interesting. This seems promising but a couple of questions though, what do you mean here when you say "Since, there is only one class we can't continue this process for this data"? Is it because there's just one target label in y_train? Also, once I have the predictions through this, how can I use them to check the accuracy of the predictions? Again, sorry if I don't make sense.

Comment: Updated answer with more details on this.

Comment: You can see my X_test and y_test in my edit. Sorry for all the confusion as I said I am still learning.I would like to let you know that this is just one class that I have showed in the question I posted, actually there are 6 more classes like that that I have to do the same for. Also, I checked my f1_score on the training data it gives me a 100% score which seems good but I am not sure if everything is correct because you have used the X_train in the prediction so maybe the score would be a 100% since the data has already been fit using X_train and y_train.

Comment: Once, I have trained the classifiers to give me the best predictions based on best confidence levels, for which I can test it on the training instances using `cross_val_predict` without messing with test data, I want to finally predict using the X_test so that it gives me y_preds and then get the `f1_score` on the y_preds and y_test_sl. Once again I am sorry if I am confusing you. If you want to be more clear you can ask more question. Your help means a lot and I would definitely mention your contribution in my project.

Comment: Do you want to train each classifier with all the training data, then perform predictions on the test data using the first classifier, then perform predictions on the second classifier on instances for which the first classifier had confidence < 60%, and so on for all classifiers? If this is the case, all you need is the ensemble method in the code I wrote, it will predict the class with maximum probability over all classifiers for each test instance.

Comment: This is what I need finally. Can you point out what changes do I need to make in the code and where? Definitely this problem is solved then.

Comment: With your code won't I need a threshold of 60% anymore? Would it automatically choose the instances with the best probability among the three classifiers and give me the predictions based on the best probability?

Comment: When I try to return the highest probabilities instead of predicted classes (which I was able to get successfully) as you mentioned I get `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`. What can I do for the function to return the predicted probabilities as I need these to plot `roc-curves`.

Comment: I am not sure what issue you are having. When I run my code to return the highest probabilities as specified in the answer, it runs works as expected. Perhaps you could post another question and link to it or otherwise provide more details.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: I posted a new question regarding ROC-curves from your function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661591/higher-roc-auc-and-f-1-scores-but-poor-looking-roc-curves