# Higher ROC-AUC and F-1 scores but poor looking ROC-curves

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-visualization, multiclass-classification

I recreated a new Ensemble method that does Voting manually between my three classifiers. (Courtesty of Daniel who helped me make the function from here: [Improving the prediction score by use of confidence level of classifiers on instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396961/improving-the-prediction-score-by-use-of-confidence-level-of-classifiers-on-inst)).

The purpose of this manual voting was to accept the answers for each instance for the most confident classifier. Below is the code with their accuracy scores:

```
# parameters for random forest
rfclf_params = {
    'n_estimators': 500, 
    'bootstrap': True, 
    'class_weight':None, 
    'criterion':'gini',
    'max_depth':None, 
    'max_features':'auto',
    'warm_start': True,
    'random_state': 41
    # ... fill in the rest you want here
}

# Fill in svm params here
svm_params = {
    'C': 100,
    'probability':True,
    'random_state':42
}

# KNeighbors params go here
kneighbors_params= {
    'n_neighbors': 5,
    'weights':'distance'
}

y_test_classes = (y_test_sl, y_test_lim, y_test_shale, y_test_sandlim, y_test_ss, y_test_dol, y_test_sand)
classifiers = [RandomForestClassifier, SVC, KNeighborsClassifier]
params = [rfclf_params, svm_params, kneighbors_params]
y_trains_classes= (y_train_sl, y_train_lim, y_train_shale, y_train_sandlim, 
                   y_train_ss, y_train_dol, y_train_sand)
y_classes_names = ("shaly limestone", "limestone", "shale", "sandy lime", 
                   "shaly sandstone", "dolomite", "sandstone")

#Just get predictions
for y_trains, y_test, y_strings in zip(y_trains_classes, y_test_classes, y_classes_names):
    y_preds_test = ensemble_test(classifiers, params, X_train, y_trains, X_test_prepared)
    print("\n","Accuracy score for", y_strings, "=", accuracy_score(y_test, y_preds_test))
    print("f1_score for", y_strings, "=", f1_score(y_test, y_preds_test,
                                                        average = 'weighted', labels=np.unique(y_preds_test)))
    print("roc auc score for", y_strings, "=", roc_auc_score(y_test, y_preds_test,
                                                                  average = 'weighted'))

Accuracy score for shaly limestone = 0.949514563107
f1_score for shaly limestone = 0.949653574035
roc auc score for shaly limestone = 0.933362369338

 Accuracy score for limestone = 0.957281553398
f1_score for limestone = 0.957272532095
roc auc score for limestone = 0.957311555515

 Accuracy score for shale = 0.95145631068
f1_score for shale = 0.948556595316
roc auc score for shale = 0.845505617978

 Accuracy score for sandy lime = 0.998058252427
f1_score for sandy lime = 0.998008114117
roc auc score for sandy lime = 0.95

 Accuracy score for shaly sandstone = 0.996116504854
f1_score for shaly sandstone = 0.998054474708
roc auc score for shaly sandstone = 0.5

 Accuracy score for dolomite = 1.0
f1_score for dolomite = 1.0
roc auc score for dolomite = 1.0

 Accuracy score for sandstone = 0.996116504854
f1_score for sandstone = 0.996226826208
roc auc score for sandstone = 0.997995991984
```

When I want to plot an ROC-curves I know that I need to get `predict_probas` from this function so again, referring to suggestion from the link earlier I made the function return probabilities instead:

```
def ensemble_proba(classifiers, params, X_train, y_train, X_test):
    best_preds_test = np.zeros((len(X_test), 2))
    classes_test = np.unique(y_train)

    for i in range(len(classifiers)):
        # Construct the classifier by unpacking params 
        # store classifier instance
        clf_test = classifiers[i](**params[i])
        # Fit the classifier as usual and call predict_proba
        clf_test.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_preds_test = clf_test.predict_proba(X_test)
        # Take maximum probability for each class on each classifier 
        # This is done for every instance in X_test
        # see the docs of np.maximum here: 
        # https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html
        best_preds_test = np.maximum(best_preds_test, y_preds_test)

    # map the maximum probability for each instance back to its corresponding class
    preds_test = np.array([classes_test[np.argmax(pred)] for pred in best_preds_test])
    return np.array([np.amax(pred_probs) for pred_probs in best_preds_test])
```

Now, since I wanted to plot ROC-curves for all the classes in the test set I did the following and got ROC-curves that look very different then what I had expected to since my ROC-AUC scores are pretty good except for "shaly sandstone" class.

```
for y_trains, y_test, y_strings in zip(y_trains_classes, y_test_classes, y_classes_names):
    y_scores_ensemble_all = ensemble_proba(classifiers, params, X_train, y_trains, X_test_prepared)
    fpr_ensemble_all, tpr_ensemble_all, thresholds_ensemble_all = roc_curve(y_test_all,
                                                                              y_scores_ensemble_all)

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plot_roc_curve(fpr_ensemble_all, tpr_ensemble_all, "Ensemble manual voting")
    plt.legend(loc="lower right", fontsize=16)
    plt.title('ROC curve of Ensemble manual voting of  %s'%(y_strings))
    plt.axis([-0.01, 1.01, -0.01, 1.01])
    plt.show()
```

[First two classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCKBE.png)

[Next two classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHmb6.png)

[Next two classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjNNs.png)

[Last class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPP51.png)

Why does the curves look like this when their F1-scores and ROC-AUC scores are pretty good for almost all classes but they perform poorly on the ROC-curves? Did I do something wrong when I returned the probabilties from my function or are the curves supposed to look like this due to some reasons?

Comment: There is an awful lot of unpack here. What is `ensemble_test`? Have you tried plotting your ROC curves before ensembling? Are you trying to predict each rock type separately?

Comment: `ensemble_test` is just another method of voting as I mentioned in the question. I I am trying to predict the rock type based on the log data I get. I tried to train the classifiers on individual rock type and my `X_train` remains the same while `y_trains` are a series of rocks as you can see. I did the same with Automatic voting, `RandomForestClassifier`, `SVM` & `KNearestNeighbor`, but my ROC plots work perfectly as I expected them to after getting good prediction scores of `f1` and `roc_auc` from them, but when I do this on `ensemble_test`,  it looks awfully bad as you can see.